# Why does my ReSharper modified form.Show() code not work?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, resharper

I am using ReSharper with C#/VS2010.  I am running a seperate thread that needs to open a form to display some information to the user on the main UI thread.  My code was this (which works great):

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    DisplayDownload form2 = new DisplayDownload();

    form2.TopMost = true;
    form2.Show();
}));
```

ReSharper wanted to change it to this and I let it (but the following code does not display the form at all):

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
   using (var form2 = new DisplayDownload {TopMost = true})
      {
         form2.Show();
      }
}));
```

The form never displays anymore with the ReSharper modified code.  It works fine if I go back to the old code.

Why does it not work after ReSharper changed it?  Can someone please explain it to me what is causing the modified code to not display the form anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe its due the USING keyword. Considering that Show() is not blocking call, after that the program leaves using statement and Dispose() of the form called.

Regards.

Comment: I should never encapsulate Show() calls inside of a USING statement?

Comment: Not a Show() call but do not incapsulate Form object in Using statement IN THIS case, in other case, if you for example call ShowDialog(), could be acceptable solution.

Comment: Yes, never use using with Show().  Show leave the form in a non-modal state whereas Dispose (the end brace of the using) closes it...  R# doesn't make the distinction there.  It just sees that you've instantiated a Form object locally and that it is IDisposable so it should be disposed before the exit of the application.  The form object will be 'live' after the method exits, so you should think about making it a member of the enclosing class instead of a local to the method.  Otherwise, every time this code is called you're going to create a new form.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work after Resharper change it because you are disposing the form just after you show it, so you did not have the change to make it shown.

However Resharper wants to change it to that way because you are creating `IDisposable` object "the `DisplayDownload` form" inside a method, and after you finish using it "Resharper doesn't know that `Show()` method will keep the form showing..", you does not dispose it, however you should declare your `DisplayDownload` at a class level and only show it on your method. like:

```
DisplayDownload form2 = new DisplayDownload();

private void YourSubMethod()
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {
        form2.Show();
    }));
}
```

Comment: Is it not alright to just leave it like I have in the first example code in my post?  It works fine in the first example just not in the ReSharper example.  Is the USING statement causing the problem?